# Take a few numbers and give the average of the numbers

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, numbers, average

I want to get some numbers from the user so that this continues until the user presses the number -1. After hitting the number -1, the program will give him the average of the previous numbers. My code works but miscalculates the mean. what is the problem?

```
  sum = 0
  count = 0 
  x = []
  while x != -1 :
      x = int(input())
      sum += x
      count += 1

  averagex = sum / count 
  print(averagex)
```

Comment: Did you step through your code? What happens when the user inputs `-1`? Helpful links: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop terminates *after* the user enters `-1`. This means on the last iteration 1 will be subtracted from the total and `count` will be one higher than it should be. Try this:

```
  while True:
      x = int(input())
      if x == -1:
          break
      sum += x
      count += 1
```

Comment: Glad to help! Feel free to mark this answer as correct if it answered your question and you think it might be helpful to others :)

Answer (score 0):

Fow now your verification of the input is done at `while x != -1` which is executed **after** the input, the sum and the count part, so the `-1` will be part of the result, thing that you don't want.

A simple `if` will fix that :

```
total, count, x = 0, 0, 0
while True:
    x = int(input("Enter a value: "))
    if x == -1:
        break
    total += x
    count += 1
```

*Avoid using builtin function names, such as `sum`, for variable naming*